# Mongoose Partial Search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to search  location from  collection field property_address .It contains values like SouthEx, New delhi. If i search southEx , New delhi,Delhi,India ,it will display the result that contains southEx,New Delhi.

How we will do it using mongoose search?

Answer (score 1):

Form:

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q"/>
</form>
```

Ajax request on keyup of input text

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup','#q',function(){
   if($(this).val()!=='' || $(this).val!=undefined){
      var query=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
         url:'http://localhost:3000/search?q='+ query,
         type:'GET',
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
              if(response.status=='ok'){
                 console.log(response.search_results);
              }
          },
         error:function(){
             alert('Failed to search address');
         } 
      });
   }
});
</script>
```

server.js

```
app.get('/search',function(req,res) {

 if(req.query && req.query.q) {

     var q = req.query.q;

     YourModel.find({"property_address": new RegExp('^'+q+'$', "i")}, function(err, data) {
   if(!err && data) {
     return res.json({status:'ok',search_results:data});
   }
});
} else {
     return res.json({status:'error',message:'No input'});
}
});
```

Comment: It will return  value when i  search   southEx , but when i search for southEx, New Delhi or southEx, New Delhi ,India.  it dosen't return any value.

Is it anyway to search text without creating index?

Answer (score 0):

this should be your query :

```
await YourModel.find({ "property_address": new RegExp(req.query.q) })
```

but it will only find in string values, so don't try it on numberic values it won't work :)

i don't know maybe there should be a higher performance way, if you found a higher performance way comment and let me know, thanks.